# Python - Kivy - Screen Manager - Changing a Button Text with Text Input issue

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm currently working with Kivy for GUI Design I was looking for a way to change a button text with a TextInput from another screen.

My Screen 1 has a button that will work as a "label", there I have another button to go to screen 2.

Screen 2 is a Keypad with a Textinput on it, there I put the numbers that I want to set in the button "label" from screen 1.

With a button called "ENTER" I want to go back to the screen 1 and update the new text in the button "label". But I can't figure out how to do it properly.

Here is a little piece of the project code **main.py** :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class Main_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class Input_Number_Inch_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class Input_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class Screen_Management(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("screen3.kv")

class Screen3App(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation

Screen3App().run()
```

the **screen3.kv** file:

```
    Screen_Management:
        id: screen_management
        transition: FadeTransition()
        Main_Screen:
            id: main_screen
            name: "main_screen_name"
            manager: screen_management
        Input_Screen:
            id: tire_setup_screen_id
            name: "tire_setup_screen_name"
            manager: screen_management
        Input_Number_Inch_Screen:
            name: "inch_screen"
            manager: screen_management

<Main_Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30, .30, .30]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        background_color: .52, .52, .52, 1
        bold: 1
        color: .0078,.67,.69,1
        size_hint: .2, 1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "center_y": .5}
        on_release: app.root.current = "tire_setup_screen_name"
        text: " INPUTS "
        font_size: 30

    # Screen 1: Input Screen
    <Input_Screen>:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: [.30, .30, .30]
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            pos: (160,150)
            size_hint: (.8, .8)
            Button:
                background_color: .52, .52, .52, 1
                bold: 1
                color: .0078,.67,.69,1
                font_size: 30
                text: "INPUT\n(Inch)"
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 150
                on_release: app.root.current = "inch_screen"
                # This button will go to the screen2

            Button:
                id: inch_input
                background_color: .52, .52, .52, 1
                bold: 1
                color: .0078,.67,.69,1
                font_size: 100
                text: "THIS IS THE TEXT THAT I WANT TO UPDATE"

    # Screen 2: Input Inch Screen Data
    <Input_Number_Inch_Screen>:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: [.30, .30, .30]
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        GridLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            display: entry
            rows: 6
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10

    # This is the TextInput 
            BoxLayout:
                TextInput:
                    id: entry
                    font_size: 75
                    multiline: False

    # This will be the button that would go back to the screen and update
    # the button text with the new text entered in the TextInput
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 10
                Button:
                    background_color: .52, .52, .52, 1
                    bold: 1
                    color: .0078,.67,.69,1
                    font_size: 40
                    text:"ENTER"
                    on_release: app.root.current = "tire_setup_screen_name"
                    on_press: app.root.inch_input.text = entry.text
```

Any comment to help it would be great, thanks for your time.

Comment: In your screen3.kv file, there is a child widget, Main_Screen in <Screen_Management> widget rule but there is no <Main_Screen> widget rule in screen3.kv, and also missing Main_Screen class in main.py. Can you please provide Main_Screen.

Comment: Now I add them to the thread, I did not include them because I don't consider them important for the problem, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace the following in screen3.kv:

```
        on_press: app.root.inch_input.text = entry.text
```

with:

```
        on_press: root.manager.ids.tire_setup_screen_id.ids.inch_input.text = entry.text
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class Main_Screen(Screen):
    pass


class Input_Number_Inch_Screen(Screen):
    pass


class Input_Screen(Screen):
    pass


class Screen_Management(ScreenManager):
    pass


presentation = Builder.load_file("screen3.kv")


class Screen3App(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Screen3App().run()
```

### screen3.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

Screen_Management:
    id: screen_management
    transition: FadeTransition()
    Main_Screen:
        id: main_screen
        name: "main_screen_name"
        manager: screen_management
    Input_Screen:
        id: tire_setup_screen_id
        name: "tire_setup_screen_name"
        manager: screen_management
    Input_Number_Inch_Screen:
        name: "inch_screen"
        manager: screen_management

<Main_Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30, .30, .30]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        background_color: .52, .52, .52, 1
        bold: 1
        color: .0078,.67,.69,1
        size_hint: .2, 1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "center_y": .5}
        on_release: root.manager.current = "tire_setup_screen_name"
        text: " INPUTS "
        font_size: 30

# Screen 1: Input Screen
<Input_Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30, .30, .30]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        pos: (160,150)
        size_hint: (.8, .8)

        Button:
            background_color: .52, .52, .52, 1
            bold: 1
            color: .0078,.67,.69,1
            font_size: 30
            text: "INPUT\n(Inch)"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 150
            on_release: root.manager.current = "inch_screen"
            # This button will go to the screen2

        Button:
            id: inch_input
            background_color: .52, .52, .52, 1
            bold: 1
            color: .0078,.67,.69,1
            font_size: 100
            text: "THIS IS THE TEXT THAT I WANT TO UPDATE"

# Screen 2: Input Inch Screen Data
<Input_Number_Inch_Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30, .30, .30]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    GridLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        display: entry
        rows: 6
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10

# This is the TextInput
        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: entry
                font_size: 75
                multiline: False

# This will be the button that would go back to the screen and update
# the button text with the new text entered in the TextInput
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 10
            Button:
                background_color: .52, .52, .52, 1
                bold: 1
                color: .0078,.67,.69,1
                font_size: 40
                text:"ENTER"
                on_release: root.manager.current = "tire_setup_screen_name"
                on_press: root.manager.ids.tire_setup_screen_id.ids.inch_input.text = entry.text
```

### Outpu

[image]

Comment: Excellent! It works perfectly, however, I would look to understand that line of the code. Thank you for your help!